# C++11 lambda function definition in if-else

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, auto

How do I do something like this, but in a way that will compile, and hopefully without insane typedefs?

```
auto b;
auto g;
if (vertical)
{
    b = [=, &b_](int x, int y) -> bool { return b_[x + y*w]; };
    g = [=, &g_](int x, int y) -> int& { return g_[x + y*w]; };
}
else
{
    b = [=, &b_](int x, int y) -> bool { return b_[y + x*w]; };
    g = [=, &g_](int x, int y) -> int& { return g_[y + x*w]; };
}
```

Comment: Declare `b` and `g` as `std::function` objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `auto b;` and `auto g;` would need to be initialised so that the compiler would be able to determined their type (but I think you know this).

Since you don't seem to mind the specifics of type (you've declared them `auto` anyway);

```
std::function<bool(int,int)> b;
std::function<int&(int,int)> g;
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Repetition? In the declaration or the calculation?

Comment: The declaration. I.e. I have to mentally convert `(int x, int y) -> int&` to `int& (int, int)`. Ok I guess it's not that bad and that's presumably the best C++11 can do, but I felt I might be missing a more elegant method.

Answer (score 7):

The reason this does not compile is the improper use of `auto`. You can avoid conditional creation of lambdas altogether by changing their definition a little:

```
int mx = vertical ? 1 : w;
int my = vertical ? w : 1;
auto b = [=, &b_](int x, int y) -> bool { return b_[mx*x + my*y]; };
auto g = [=, &g_](int x, int y) -> int& { return g_[mx*x + my*y]; };
```

The idea is to set multipliers `mx` and `my` conditionally. This lets you construct your lambdas unconditionally, so you could use `auto` in your declaration.

Comment: That's a nice solution.

Comment: I went with your solution in my code, but gave the tick to the other answer since this one is more of a workaround that only works with this specific example (a good workaround though). Thanks!